# Repeat VBA code and change values based on other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to automate an excel sheet using the code below. It works for the first part of what i need it for but i can't figure out the next part.

I need to repeat this code for every value in a sheet called Materials. Each cell contains a different material number. The material number used for the first set of data Result (A2) would then be overwritten by the next available value from Column A in the Materials sheet and so forth until the last cell.

So basically this creates the first set and i want to copy and paste it with updated values in column A from the Materials sheet. Hope that makes sense.

```
Sub Test2()

Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
    Set sh4 = Sheets("Template")
    Set sh5 = Sheets("Result")
    lr = sh4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh4.Range("A2:E2" & lr)
        rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

        Sheets("Materials").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Result").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Result").Select

Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Worksheets("Result").Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Result").Range("A2")
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow&)
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You seem to be copying from Template to Result at the beginning, but then you copy A2 on Materials to A2 on Result which presumably overwrites part of what you copied in the first place?

Comment: My understanding was that the first copy provides the source data to be copied down through all other cells containing data copied from Template.

Comment: Well you can see what is actually happening, but when you copy from Template to Result where does it go? Are you saying that you want to copy a list of items in A2 downwards on the Materials sheet and paste into A2 and down on the Results sheet?

Comment: Hey SJR, sorry for the late reply. I Wasn't able to upload an example for you from my work.

so, check the PDF file for more details with some screenshots.
http://www.molszak.nl/michael/PPPrep_info.pdf

i also uploaded the xls file so you you can take a look yourself.
http://www.molszak.nl/michael/PPPrep_file_new4.xlsm

thx in advance for you help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: No probs, I've been away myself. Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Absolutely. Been playing around a bit more but to no avail. Would appreciate if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess because I'm not clear from your picture what exactly you are after, and seems to differ from your actual file

```
Sub Test2()

Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, rng As Range, r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh4 = Sheets("Template")
Set sh5 = Sheets("Result")
Set rng = sh4.Range("B2:E2" & lr)

With Sheets("Materials")
    For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        sh5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Offset(, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
        sh5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Value = r.Value
    Next r
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i had to adjust it just a little bit to extend the range on the Template sheet but it's perfect! it works just like i wanted it.

Thank you so much.